# Displaying JSON object on blade template

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I'm trying to display a JSON object that is returned to my blade template that should look the output below

```
2007 | Kanye | UltralightBeam  
2008 | JayZ  | 99 Problems
```

JSON looks like this

```
{
    "2007":{
        "name" : "Kanye",
        "song" : "UltralightBeam"
    },
    "2008":{
        "name" : "JayZ",
        "song" : "99 Problems"        
    }
}
```

So far I have something like this that shows the name and song

```
@foreach($data['data_obj'] as $obj)
    {{$obj['name']}} | {{$obj['song']}} 
@endforeach
```

But I'm just not sure how I can get it to show the year as well?

Any guidance would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to use [`key => value`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) syntax:

```
@foreach ($data['data_obj'] as $year => $obj)
    {{ $year }} | {{ $obj['name'] }} | {{ $obj['song'] }} 
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

**you could use this**

```
 @foreach ($data['data_obj'] as $year => $obj)
 {{ $year }} | {{ $obj->name }} | {{ $obj->song }} 
 @endforeach
```